# R: Wordcloud: giving partial words + conjunctions

Tags: r, word-cloud

Using the R wordcloud and tm packages for the first time, following this:

[rwordcloud](https://georeferenced.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/rwordcloud/)

As you can see below, I'm getting two strange errors in my output:  it's giving partial words sometimes (busi, peopl, everi), and it's counting contractions as their own words ('ll, 're).

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this?

[image]

Comment: You should share the code you used to generate this plot. Did you stem the words? Unless you create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

A reproducible example would really help. Nevertheless, I might give a hint that is hopefully useful. If your word list is stored in `my_words`, it could  help if you add

```
my_words <- tm_map(my_words,content_transformer(removePunctuation))
```

in the code. This may at least remove the occurrences of "'ll" and "'re". Maybe....

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your assistance.

Looks like this is to do with stemming, as once I removed the stemming aspects of the code, everything has worked out fine.

This got me to where I want to be, now I just need to start looking through and seeing which words I do in fact want to stem.

[Text-mining with the tm-package - word stemming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069406/text-mining-with-the-tm-package-word-stemming)